# Polygons created for holes after running ST_Collect

Tags: shapefile, sql, ogr2ogr

I ran an ST_Collect query on a polygon dataset using ogr2gor -dialect sqlite -sql

```
SELECT ST_Collect(geometry),id
FROM wl_test
GROUP BY id
```

The result is a multipart polygon, which is what I want, but it also creates polygons for some of the holes, which I do not want. I created a point shapefile of all the vertices from the resultant dataset and labeled the points according to vertex id. The vertices of the polygons that should be holes are in reverse order as a hole is required to be in a shapefile.

Why are polygons being created for some of the holes after running ST_Collect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had this issue too previously. I assume you are using a shapefile to do this? This was my mistake too. Adapt the script to run for Mapinfo .tab files. Firstly, convert your input shapefile to a .tab file (QGIS does this no problem). Try this method and see what happen. Perhaps post your whole script for this to give us more insight?

Comment: Converting to mapinfo tab format solved the issue. Could this be a shapefile issue??